# What is the relationship between each of the references to nodeId, frame, frameTreeNodeId, layerId and layerTreeId (and others) in a chrome trace file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for current documentation in relation to the structure of a chrome trace file.

In a trace file, for example, there are frames that relate to each other using a parent property. There are frames that are associated with a nodeId, but there are also nodeId’s that do not have an associated frame. Similarly, there are frames with layerId’s and frames without.

Is there a document anywhere that describes how all these objects relate to each other? Are they parallel structures? Are they part of one hierarchy? Are nodes referred to uniquely, or can a different nodeId refer to the same object?

Here's what I've found so-far:

In my search for an answer, I’ve discovered the Chrome DevTools Protocol documentation [1] which seems to refer to each of these, but I’ve been unable to discover how they relate to each other.

I’ve grepped through the 19 GB of chrome source code with nothing much to show for, other than finding TimelineModel.ts [2] with many (if not all) of those references.

I’ve also discovered the Trace Event Format [3], which describes some of the fields in a trace file, but it was last updated in 2016 and does not contain references to nodeId’s or layerId’s.

Although not directly related to chrome, a WebKit file [4] I’ve discovered has all of these references and includes extras such as a shadow tree, a compositing tree and an accessibility structure.

Any help would be welcome.

1. https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/
2. https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/af7ba130f6fe898ebe08c15e29438b83e7c40d7d/front_end/models/timeline_model/TimelineModel.ts
3. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/preview
4. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WebKit/WebKit/main/Source/WebInspectorUI/Versions/Inspector-iOS-13.0.json

Comment: Layer is a rendering thing, not related to structure directly, which you can observe in devtools -> Rendering (or Layers) panel. As for others, you'll have to study their relation in source code, which should be easy if you load it in an IDE that can jump to usages and peek definitions under cursor e.g. VSCode, WebStorm, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm, but it's clear that there is a relationship between a layerId, a nodeId and a frame, since there are references in the trace file that reference all three in the same object.

Comment: The relationship is that an object has such properties. Like human has legs and a nose :-)

Comment: Understood. Why is it that some objects do not have such properties. A human without a head is not often encountered in a living state.